# GMail API SendAs GET not showing displayname without alias

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-apis-explorer

Can't seem to find questions that address this directly but does anyone know why the endpoint https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/list does not list the default displayName when an alias is NOT set up?

```
{
  "sendAs": [
    {
      "sendAsEmail": "foo@gmail.com",
      "displayName": "",
      "replyToAddress": "",
      "signature": "",
      "isPrimary": true,
      "isDefault": true
    }
  ]
}
```

From my testing, it looks like if you create an alternate display name using the steps listed here https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8158?hl=en, the response will show up as

```
{
  "sendAs": [
    {
      "sendAsEmail": "foo@gmail.com",
      "displayName": "New Alternate Name",
      "replyToAddress": "",
      "signature": "",
      "isPrimary": true,
      "isDefault": true
    }
  ]
}
```

And if you add another email address to alias, you get

```
{
  "sendAs": [
    {
      "sendAsEmail": "foo@gmail.com",
      "displayName": "New Alternate Name",
      "replyToAddress": "",
      "signature": "",
      "isPrimary": true,
      "isDefault": true
    },
    {
      "sendAsEmail": "foo2@gmail.com",
      "displayName": "Foo 2 Name",
      "replyToAddress": "",
      "signature": "",
      "treatAsAlias": true,
      "verificationStatus": "accepted",
      "isDefault": false
    }
  ]
}
```

But if you revert your main email's displayname to the original default, you get

```
{
  "sendAs": [
    {
      "sendAsEmail": "foo@gmail.com",
      "displayName": "",
      "replyToAddress": "",
      "signature": "",
      "isPrimary": true,
      "isDefault": true
    },
    {
      "sendAsEmail": "foo2@gmail.com",
      "displayName": "Foo 2 Name",
      "replyToAddress": "",
      "signature": "",
      "treatAsAlias": true,
      "verificationStatus": "accepted",
      "isDefault": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Was running into issues locally with Java but testing it on the "Try this API" features creates the same results so I am thinking this is WAD and I might need to be using something else.

Answer (score 1):

The method [list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/list) of the resource `user.settings.sendAs` returns an [SendAs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs#SendAs) object, which contains a field called `displayName` and it is describe as:

> A name that appears in the "From:" header for mail sent using this alias.

It means that if you aren't using an alias, it will be empty. If you want to retrieve the full name of your account you can use the Admin API, with the method [get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/get) of the resource [users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users#resource:-user), but it is restricted to admin users of your domain.

### Reference:

- [Gmail: user.settings.sendAs: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/list)
- [Gmail: sendAs resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs#SendAs)
- [Admin SDK: users: get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/get)
- [Users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users#resource:-user)

Comment: Amazing there is not a way to get the display for the user who you have the OAuth token for!